# How to create an instance of a class in Rails, giving each new instance 5 has_many through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make an instance of my `Test` class get five practice questions through a join class when it is initialised. If a test is an "exam" then it should just get 5 exam questions without a join class. (the question types have different models)

So far It doesn't behave the way I expect

```
self.practice_questions = []
```

it makes 5 join classes every time, but the array of self.practice_questions stays empty.

```
def get_questions
  puts "ASDASDASDASDSAD"
  array = []
  if self.for_practice
    puts "ASDASDASOASKODKSAOKDASODKOASKDSAOKDOASKDOASK"

    PracticeQuestion.sort_for_selection[0...5].each do |question|
      array << question
      question.use_practice_question
    end
  elsif for_practice === false
    puts self.exam_questions
    if self.exam_questions.length ===0
     grab 5 unused exam type questions
     ExamQuestion.unused[0...5].each do |question|
     puts "grabbing question #{question.title}"
     question.test = self
     question.use_question
    end
  end
  puts "hello"
  puts self.practice_questions.length
  self.practice_questions ||= array
  self.save
  puts self.practice_questions.length

  self.practice_questions.each {|question| puts question.title}
end
```

Comment: `self.practice_questions ||= array` will only assign the array if `self.practice_questions` is false or nil, are you sure it's one of those?

Answer (score 0):

`self.practice_questions ||= array` will only assign the array if `self.practice_questions` is false or nil, are you sure it's one of those?

If `practice_questions` is a has_many, try one of this:

```
array.each do |el|
  self.practice_questions << el
end
```

or:

```
self.practice_questions_ids = array.map(&:id)
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference